# how to access model data returned from model hook in the same route (in ember)?

Tags: ember.js

The project's data will be edited in a template. Without saving it if i navigate to other link willTransition action will be executed but how to access the 'project' model data within the same route?? (without using controller)

//routes/records/edit

```
    return RSVP.hash({
        project: this.get('store').findRecord('project', params.id),
        ..: this.get('store').findAll('...')
    });
},
actions: {
    willTransition(transition) {
        if (project.isDirty) { //how to use project which is returned by model hook
            if (!confirm('unsaved is it okay!!!')) {
                transition.abort();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this.controller.get('model') should return the model if you are setting your 'project' in model or if it is a controller property then can be accessed by this.controller.get('project')

Comment: That worked:-). Is there any other way without using controller??

Comment: Model is a controller property,  so to access it you will have to do this.
If you wish to use directly then set it as route property and access it using `this.get('propertyName')` . But I am not sure if you can access `isDirty` on that property

Answer (score 0):

```
this.modelFor('record').project.get('hasDirtyAttributes');
```

`.modelFor('record')` will get the model from the route record, `.project` will get the RSVP within that model, and `.get('hasDirtyAttributes')` is a property of the model data that is set to true if the model data has changed.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17263892)

Comment: It will always return 'false' inspite of changes made to that project model data in the template because I have used 'changeset' in the template. without 'changeset' it will work.

Comment: @GovindSamrow The question is how to get the model data, and that bit of code will get it... How is that not an answer to the question?

Comment: @GovindSamrow Recommending further explanation is different than not being an answer, but thanks for the input.